# get file path from current project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, system.io.file

In my Visual Studio console application my project is located in the below location:

```
c:\MyProject\FilesToUpload\test.txt
```

I am trying to access this file using the following code:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"FilesToUpload\", "test.txt");
```

But this path returns: `c:\MyProject\bin\debug\net461\FilesToUpload\test.txt`

The path I would like to get is:  `c:\MyProject\FilesToUpload\test.txt`

Comment: Did you already host your project in specific web server ? not the one from visual studio.

Comment: What do you plan to do when you aren't just running the code in development and have actually deployed it to production? Surely there won't be a project folder then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Environment.CurrentDirectory` will return the path from which your program is currently running. What you will need to do is decide on one of the following:

- A relation between that path and the directory "FilesToUpload".
- A hard-coded path, such as `c:\MyProject\FilesToUpload\`
- A configurable path, which you can then specify and read in your application. **Personally, I'd prefer this option, as it will not be as dependent on where you run the application from.**

In the first case, you could use something like this:

```
var relation = @"..\..\..\FilesToUpload\";
var currPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, relation, "test.txt");
```

---

**Update / clarification:**

For the first option, in your case (your example), using a relative path should effectively change your returned path from:

```
c:\MyProject\bin\debug\net461\FilesToUpload\test.txt
```

To:

```
c:\MyProject\bin\debug\net461\..\..\..\FilesToUpload\test.txt
```

Try this, and see how if it works - If the path is not exactly correct, you should be able to figure out how to adjust it.

Comment: what is this relation? I just changed name of my project in variable relation and it still returns path from bin folder

Comment: The path returned from `Environment.CurrentDirectory` will still be the same, that will be unchanged. What you want to do is add a relative path, which will move you from the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` directory, to the directory you want. In your example, I think that will be three directories up (i.e. `..\..\..`, before entering `FilesToUpload`.

Comment: @James I've updated my answer to make this part more clear.

Answer (score 1):

"Environment.CurrentDirectory" return correct path. Your application is an "exe" file but not source files. And it runs from a compile output directory.  You don't need to get file from the "c:\MyProject\FilesToUpload\test.txt" but you to need change "Copy to Output Directory" property of the "test.txt" to "Copy Always".
[image: File properties]